# How to wrap my query output with single quotation

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I often read records from my database and use notepad++ to processing the receipt in this format:

```
'xxxxxxxxx'    
'xxxxxxxxx',
'xxxxxxxxx',
'xxxxxxxxx'
```

Is there a way I can use SQL query to do this once.

Sample query I ran is:

```
Select ReceiptNo 
from My_table 
where TIN = 'KEYVALUE'
```

Comment: It's not clear at all what you are asking here.  Do you want to have the receiptno wrapped in single quotes?

Comment: Yes.looking at the query, i want the result to look:'ReceiptNo'

Comment: What are you outputting _to_?  An app?  A file?  A report? It may be a lot easier to add quotes and commas at that layer rather than in SQL.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward concatenation.  You need to use 4 quotes here, though:  the first and last are your wrapper quotes which contain the string.  The inner 2 quotes are your actual quote to use, and an escape quote.

```
SELECT
  '''' + CAST(ReceiptNo as varchar(100)) + ''''
FROM
  My_Table
WHERE
  TIN = 'KEYVALUE'
```

Comment: This is fine but you did not include the comma.I will use your code as guide to do that

Comment: If comma at the end of each row is needed, you might want to replace last `''''` with `''','`

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try below:

```
SELECT
  '''' + CAST(ReceiptNo as varchar(100)) + ''','
FROM
  My_Table
WHERE
  TIN = 'KEYVALUE'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ''''+ cast(ReceiptNo as varchar(10)) + ''',' as ReceiptNo
FROM My_table
WHERE TIN = 'T'
```

Here is my [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2ec5/3)

Answer (score -4):

You can use CONCAT function to append single quote. do like

```
SELECT concat( "'", DATEBASEFIELDNAME, "'" )
```

Comment: CONCAT doesn't exist in SQL Server.

Comment: In Sql server is easy to concat, Use like
select '''' + DATABASEFIELDNAME + '''' from TABLENAME

Comment: But you say here to use the `CONCAT` function which **does not exist**

Comment: no need to use concat function in sql server as it was for mysql

Comment: Well, CONCAT exists in SQL Server 2012. However this question is about SQL Server 2008, not SQL Server 2012 *OR* MySQL.